# Yii2 Kartik-V SideNav widget pass url method

Tags: url, navigation, widget, yii2

How do we pass url method in the kartik v  sidenav widget

```
      echo SideNav::widget([ 
           'type' => $type, 'encodeLabels' => false,
           'heading' => $heading,
           'items' => [
                 Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                            ['label' => 'LOGIN',  'url' => '', 'active' => ($item == 'login')] :
                            ['label' => 'LOGOUT', 'url' => 'site/logout', 'linkOptions' =>  ['data-method' => 'post']],

                    ],
                ]);
```

I get error as logout needs method post
Where do we pass the data method in this widget

Comment: The LOGOUT method needs the method POST

Comment: I saw that i can use $url= Html::a("LOGOUT",['site/logout'],['data-method' => 'post']); but how to put that url in the above widget

Answer (score 0):

I also use  kartk v sidenav widget andthis is my SiteController

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                .......
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }


    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

in sidenav i simply have this

```
['label' => 'logout',  'url'=>Url::to(['/site/logout'])],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the `template` [option](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/sidenav) for the SideNav widget. I was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034324) SO answer.

Your code would look like this:

```
echo SideNav::widget([ 
       'type' => $type, 'encodeLabels' => false,
       'heading' => $heading,
       'items' => [
             Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                        ['label' => 'LOGIN',  'url' => '', 'active' => ($item == 'login')] :
                        ['label' => 'LOGOUT', 'icon' => 'log-out', 'url'=>Url::to(['/site/logout']), 'template' => '<a href="{url}" data-method="post">{icon}{label}</a>' ]
                ],
            ]);
```

I added an icon as a little extra example.