# YII2: How can I create a link/url in a Menu item to point to an external webpage instead of an action or view of my application

Tags: php, menu, widget, yii2

I am using the YII2 Menu Widget and did not find the solution to add attribute options like class , target on created link.

My code is below:

```
echo Menu::widget(
[
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'sidebar-menu'
    ],

    'items' => [

        [
            'label' => Yii::t('backend', 'Admin'),
            'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'icon' => 'fa-list-alt',
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'treeview',
            ],
            'items' => [
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('backend', 'External link'),
                    'url' => 'http://google.com',
                    'icon' => 'fa-list-alt',
                    'options' => [
                    'target' => '_blank',
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ],                

    ]
]
 );
```

Option target is not added on generated link.

Answer (score 11):

add the target like below through the template setting. The Options you have set in your code are the Html Options of the `li` element and not the link options.

```
'items' => [
    [
       'label' => Yii::t('backend', 'External link'),
       'url' => 'http://google.com',
       'icon' => 'fa-list-alt',
       'template'=> '<a href="{url}" target="_blank">{label}</a>',
    ],
]
```

Comment: how i can use this for basic theme?

Comment: this should work independent of the theme used, so also for the basic theme.

Answer (score 7):

Suggestions above do not seem to be working (in my case), an alternative solution is:

```
'linkOptions' => ['target' => '_blank']
```

For example

```
[
    'url' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->getBlogLink(),
    'linkOptions' => ['target' => '_blank']  ,
    'label' => \Yii::t('app', 'Blog')
]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the icon in your menu:

```
'template'=> '<a href="{url}" target="_blank">{icon}{label}</a>'
```

As regards the class you must specify it in the options key:

```
[
    'label' => 'Debug', 
    'icon' => 'fa fa-dashboard', 
    'url' => ['/debug'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'special'],
    'template'=> '<a href="{url}" target="_blank">{icon}{label}</a>',
],
```

gives the following menu:

```
<li class="special">
    <a target="_blank" href="your_site_url_here/index.php?r=debug">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <span>Debug</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: in my case the icon does not render a <i......></i> tag... it will just stay as {icon}... any reasons?

Answer (score -1):

You can add any url. For Example,

```
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['http://www.google.com']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['site/about']],
     ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['site/contact']],
    ],
    'options' => [
                    'class' => 'navbar-nav nav',
                    'id'=>'navbar-id',
                    'style'=>'font-size: 14px;',
                    'data-tag'=>'yii2-menu',
                ],
]);
```

Comment: I have updated my Menu Widget in which using option to add target attribute but not working.